# Put a clickable URL in a Bokeh plot?

Tags: javascript, python, html, bokeh

Is it possible to put a clickable URL in a Bokeh plot? I'm generating a lot of time series plots of online climate data, which are then browseable on a website. For each figure, I'd like to put a link to the original data webpage. This way users could browse the data on my site, then be able to go to the raw data webpage if necessary. Each link is different.

Could I put a clickable URL in the figure title? Or on a label in the corner?

I see that you can put a link on individual scatter points (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.0.4/docs/user_guide/examples/interaction_open_url.html), but that would be confusing in my use case. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, please refer this Bokeh Markup document:

[Bokeh Markup](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.2/docs/reference/models/widgets/markups.html#bokeh.models.Div)

For Bokeh HTMLFormatter Refer this document:

[Bokeh HTMLFormatter](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.2/docs/reference/models/widgets/tables.html?highlight=hyperlink#htmltemplateformatter)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I created a Div which contains my hyperlink, then put it underneath my figure with "full_plot = column(p1,link_div)" and then outputted full_plot to an html file. I don't understand what "HTMLFormatter" is, but I don't think I need it. Thanks!